# Correct arguments for az kusto cluster update

Tags: azure-cli, azure-data-explorer

I want to set enableStreamingIngest to true on my kusto cluster.  I'm using the Azure CLI Kusto extension installed via `az extension add -n kusto`.
According to the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/kusto/cluster?view=azure-cli-latest#az-kusto-cluster-update the correct way to set a property on the cluster is as follows:

```
az kusto cluster update --name $clusterName --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --set [propertyKey=value]
```

I have tried both enableStreamingIngest=true and properties.enableStreamingIngest=true but it appears that the cli rejects the --set argument altogether:

```
unrecognized arguments: --set enableStreamingIngest=true
```

If I just pass --set on its own:

```
unrecognized arguments: --set
```

Where can I find the correct documentation for the extension and what is the correct way to update properties on the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Running `az kusto cluster update --help` yields better documentation:

```
az kusto cluster update --name $clusterName --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --enable-streaming-ingest
```